# Create a class structure based on map with composite key and value

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a map:

```
Map<Map<String,Map>, List<Map<String, String>>> map = new HashMap();
```

What is the easiest way to refactor the following data structure and create a class structure using OOP principles?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a simple yet clear picture of what you want to achieve before starting your refactoring:

1. Can you break-down the data in your collection into business entities (orders, products, customers, ...) ?
2. What are the relationships between those data ? It could be a list of user linked to orders containing products.
3. Use the right Collection for the right usage. **HashMap** are key/value pair unordered collections. You access an element by its key (one key point to one value, no duplicate keys).
   **ArrayList** are values only ordered collections. You access an element by its integer index.

Given the following collection:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

And its representation:

```
{
  "Order-Ref-01": {
     "id": "123456"
     "client": "MrFooBar"
     "destination": "USA"
     "type": "Electronic"
  },
  "Order-Ref-02": {
    //...
  } 
}
```

You could refactor it into a list of Orders because you decided fetching by key is not needed for example.

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you could create 2+ classes to serve as business entities:

```
class Client {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  // ...
}

class Order {
  private String id;
  private Client client;
  private String destination;
  private String type;
  // ...
}
```

It's all about breaking-down your data structure into smaller parts representing your business entities and their relationships.